# cbind a series of vectors in the global environment

Tags: r

I have created a set of vectors in the global environment by doing the following:

```
for (i in 1:31) {
    assign(paste0("day_",i), rnorm(30))
}
```

How do I `cbind` all of these vectors without typing each one out by name?

Comment: I want to `cbind` many vectors stored in the global environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
do.call(cbind, mget(ls(pattern = "day_*")))
```

If you want an ordered matrix by colnames, then try this:

```
output <- do.call(cbind, mget(ls(pattern = "day_*")))
ind <- order(as.numeric(sub("day_", "", colnames(output))))
output[, ind]
```

Comment: or `do.call(cbind, mget(paste0("day_",1:31) ))`

Comment: It works. Thanks. Is it not better to use `sort`rather than `order` or simply use `paste` function?